# Groupby sum in years in pandas

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as shown below. which is a sales data of two health care product starting from December 2016 to November 2018.

```
product     profit      sale_date      discount
   A         50         2016-12-01      5
   A         50         2017-01-03      4
   B         200        2016-12-24      10
   A         50         2017-01-18      3
   B         200        2017-01-28      15
   A         50         2017-01-18      6
   B         200        2017-01-28      20
   A         50         2017-04-18      6
   B         200        2017-12-08      25
   A         50         2017-11-18      6
   B         200        2017-08-21      20
   B         200        2017-12-28      30
   A         50         2018-03-18      10
   B         300        2018-06-08      45
   B         300        2018-09-20      50
   A         50         2018-11-18      8
   B         300        2018-11-28      35
```

From the above I would like to prepare below dataframe and plot that into line plot.

Expected Output

```
bought_year          total_profit
2016                 250
2017                 1250
2018                 1000
```

X axis = bought_year
Y axis = profit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `groupby` with `dt.year` and `.agg` to name your column.

```
df1 = df.groupby(df['sale_date'].dt.year).agg(total_profit=('profit','sum'))\
                            .reset_index().rename(columns={'sale_date': 'bought_year'})


print(df1)

   bought_year  total_profit
0         2016           250
1         2017          1250
2         2018          1000
```

---

```
df1.set_index('bought_year').plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]